# Is it possible to combine levels of categorical variables in a statsmodels logit model?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

Let's say I'm regressing on hair color, and I have two independent variables: income and gender.

Let's say income is a pandas column with `1`, `2`, and `3` representing these different income levels:

```
0-49,999 : 1
50,000-99,999: 2
100,000-199,999: 3
```

If I'd like in my regression results for `0-99,999` to become combined into `1` and `100,000-199,999` becomes `2`, is that possible in the statsmodels `smf` formula, or would I have to alter my dataframe and add dummy variables to represent these changes?

Comment: In general you have to recode it outside of statsmodels. For the specific case using `I(income >2)` in the formula might work to create the dummy variable that income is in category 3. (or maybe `I((income > 2).astype(int)` if patsy doesn't convert the boolean)